# Threejs 3D objects sometime disappear on Safari

Tags: ios, three.js, safari, webgl, gltf

I'm using threejs to load 3D objects on a mapbox layer. But sometimes objects disappear on Safari and Iphone.
Safari console displays the following error :
"ReferenceError : can't find variable ImageBitmap"

I'm using GLB files containing textures, we have tried to use GLTF as well but we have the same behaviour.
This issue is only on Safari and IOS devices, on Chrome for IOS it's rendering fine.
I have increased the threejs version but still the same.

Comment: `ImageBitmap` is not yet supported in Safari. You probably use this API in your code causing this issue. Can you reproduce the issue with one of the official examples? https://threejs.org/examples/ If not, it's probably an app-related issue.

Comment: In exemple some we've got this error :
"[Log] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: createImageBitmap (webgl_loader_imagebitmap.html, line 48)
(anonymous function) — three.module.js:42678"

Comment: Yeah, like I said before it's because Safari does not support this API.